# splitting text in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following jQuery code.

```
innerHtml = innerHtml + '<div class="compare-box '+ $(this).attr("offertype") +'"> <div class="compare-close"><span class="closed" onclick="RemoveCompareOffer(\''+ $(this).attr("id") + '\')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span></div>'
             + '<div class="compare-logo"><img src="' + $(this).attr("imagelink") + '" /></div><p>' + $(this).attr("offername") + '</p>'
             + '<input type="button" value="View Details" class="viewbtn" onclick="CallOfferRenderAction(\'' + $(this).attr("offercode") + '\',\'' + $(this).attr("providercode") + '\')" /></div>';
```

Whenever `$(this).attr("offertype")` contains `special-box specialoffer` I want to split and replace it with `specialoffer-compare`. How can I do this?

Comment: what u want split and replace with which string special-box  or specialoffer

Comment: I want to remove special-box, keep specialoffer and append `-compare` to specialoffer

Comment: use a variable as shown... `var temp = $(this).attr("offertype");temp = temp.indexOf("special-box specialoffer") > -1 ? "specialoffer-compare" : temp;innerHtml = innerHtml + ... + temp + ....`

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla can you post answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a temporary variable and `indexOf()` to check if a string contains a substring as shown :-

```
var temp = $(this).attr("offertype");
temp = temp.indexOf("special-box specialoffer") > -1 ? "specialoffer-compare" : temp;

innerHtml = innerHtml + '<div class="compare-box '+ temp +'"> <div class="compare-close"><span class="closed" onclick="RemoveCompareOffer(\''+ $(this).attr("id") + '\')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span></div>'
             + '<div class="compare-logo"><img src="' + $(this).attr("imagelink") + '" /></div><p>' + $(this).attr("offername") + '</p>'
             + '<input type="button" value="View Details" class="viewbtn" onclick="CallOfferRenderAction(\'' + $(this).attr("offercode") + '\',\'' + $(this).attr("providercode") + '\')" /></div>';
```